# Pure Python way to apply a unified diff to a file?

Tags: python, diff, patch

I've got a unified diff file (let's call it a patch). I need to open it, apply to a specified file and save the result back to the file. Same way as Unix `patch` tool does. I need a Python solution that I could easily call from my .py script, and so far I can't find any.

I've looked at https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API, and it looks like it can't do what I need. I also looked at https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch and https://github.com/matiasb/python-unidiff. `python-patch` seems to emulate the Unix `patch` util, but it's a command line tool and I don't understand how to call it from my .py script.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40967337/431087

Answer (score 11):

Using [python-patch](https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch):

```
import patch
pset = patch.fromfile(unified_diff_filename)
pset.apply()
```

If you want to apply to a stream / differently named output, you will have to make your own function (look how [apply](https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch/blob/63db079d88d9873f944ff27a17a4063e6da00598/patch.py#L769) is doing it, or find `def apply` in [the latest](https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch/blob/master/patch.py)).

Comment: Last release in 2015.

Comment: *> Last release in 2015.*
yes, but the repository is still updated and Python3 compatible.

Comment: It is not compatible with Python3.9+

Comment: What's the status here? Any alternatives?