# clang-format-diff.py without -i option generates patch file in format I can't apply

Tags: git, diff, patch, clang-format, difflib

I made a script to run `clang-format-diff.py` on a diff of all uncommitted changes and unpushed commits.

File called `run-clang-format.sh` in base of git directory and contains:

```
git diff -U0 --no-color origin/master | clang-format-diff.py -p1
```

When I add the `-i` option to `clang-format-diff.py` it works fine but I want to avoid this because it introduces some wacky reordering that I want to bypass. So I currently run the above shell script like so in the base of the git directory (so I get a .diff that I can review and/or edit manually before applying):

```
./run-clang-format.sh > format.diff
```

format.diff looks like this (I've never seen this "before formatting / after formatting" format):

```
--- symengine/functions.cpp (before formatting)
+++ symengine/functions.cpp (after formatting)
@@ -11,7 +11,10 @@
 extern RCP<const Basic> im3;
 extern RCP<const Basic> im5;
 
-RCP<const Basic> sqrt(RCP<const Basic> &arg) { return pow(arg, div(one, i2)); }
+RCP<const Basic> sqrt(RCP<const Basic> &arg)
+{
+    return pow(arg, div(one, i2));
+}
 
 RCP<const Basic> cbrt(RCP<const Basic> &arg)
 {
```

I tried several ways to apply this patch (from the base of the git directory):

```
$ git apply format.diff 
error: functions.cpp: No such file or directory
```

```
$ git am format.diff 
Patch format detection failed.
```

```
$ patch -p1 < format.diff 
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- symengine/functions.cpp    (before formatting)
|+++ symengine/functions.cpp    (after formatting)
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

**EDIT** The patch above could be applied if the file paths had a leading dot.

How can I either apply this patch as is or get clang-format-patch.py to create a diff in a format like this:

```
diff --git a/symengine/functions.cpp b/symengine/functions.cpp
index c2fbc01a..75ef7d63 100644
--- a/symengine/functions.cpp
+++ b/symengine/functions.cpp
@@ -11,10 +11,8 @@ extern RCP<const Basic> im2;
 extern RCP<const Basic> im3;
 extern RCP<const Basic> im5;
 
-RCP<const Basic> sqrt(RCP<const Basic> &arg)
-{
-    return pow(arg, div(one, i2));
-}
+RCP<const Basic> sqrt(RCP<const Basic> &arg) { return pow(arg, div(one, i2)); }
+
 RCP<const Basic> cbrt(RCP<const Basic> &arg)
 {
     return pow(arg, div(one, i3));
```

which is easily applied using `git apply format.diff`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this isn't the best answer but I solved this using [Pure Python way to apply a unified diff to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434679/pure-python-way-to-apply-a-unified-diff-to-a-file) after reading clang-format-diff.py

I suppose the issue is clang-format-diff.py is using `difflib.unified_diff` yet https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html doesn't explain how to apply the output manually.

So I created a new script `apply-clang-format-diff.py` in the base of the git directory that looks like:

```
import patch
import sys
pset = patch.fromfile(sys.argv[1])
pset.apply()
```

and run it like `python apply-clang-format-diff.py format.diff` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another fix. Apply this patch to `clang-format-diff.py` so that the unified diff output contains a leading dot.

```
--- clang-format-diff.py    2020-09-26 17:15:43.000000000 -0400
+++ clang-format-diff.py    2020-09-26 20:42:29.000000000 -0400
@@ -24,6 +24,7 @@
 import re
 import subprocess
 import sys
+import os
 
 if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
     from io import StringIO
@@ -111,9 +112,10 @@
     if not args.i:
       with open(filename) as f:
         code = f.readlines()
+      filepath = os.path.join(os.path.curdir, filename)
       formatted_code = StringIO(stdout).readlines()
       diff = difflib.unified_diff(code, formatted_code,
-                                  filename, filename,
+                                  filepath, filepath,
                                   '(before formatting)', '(after formatting)')
       diff_string = ''.join(diff)
       if len(diff_string) > 0:
```

Now I can `git apply` the patches (or use unix patch). But notice that the patch above (produced using `diff -u`) has no leading dots and it applies just fine using `patch`. So what gives with the default output of `clang-format-diff.py` and `difflib.unified_diff`???